# Increase the request timeout beyond 30 seconds?

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout, google-cloud-platform

I have a flexible app engine app in which I am running a set of integration tests upon request. I get a sys.exit(1) after 30 seconds every time I run it. I cannot use Task Queue or Deferred library since this is a Flexible(Not Standard) app engine project. Any ideas on how to extend this 30 second deadline? 
I also tried to change from auto scaling to manual scaling without any luck :|

Comment: Requests in flexible environment have a timeout limit of 60 minutes. What do the logs say?

Comment: I think flexible supports task queues.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, my http request is getting terminated after 120 seconds on Google App Engine Flexible environment.

Answer (score 1):

In your Flexible environment you can use pub/sub library to create background tasks. You need to create a worker service which listens to a particular queue and you can add tasks in a queue , when the task is ready it will be thrown to worker service and be taken care of by it. Here is the reference you can use to solve it, https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-pub-sub. Hope it will help :)